# TableView data disappear after scroll up

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

```
Code :

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

{
     static NSString *str=@"cellidentifier";

    customCell *cell=(customCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:str];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
       NSArray *value= [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell=[value objectAtIndex:0];
    }


    [cell setValue:[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

customCell.h

-(void)setValue:(NSString*)val;

customCell.m
-(void)setValue:(NSString *)val
{
    lbl.text=val;
}
```

I have created a UITableView with customCell.It is working fine.When i scroll up the data in tableview are disappearing and looks empty.what is wrong with code?
any help will appreciated.[image]

Comment: Does the cell have the identifier set within the NIB file?

Comment: Mmmm has you checked the values in [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]?. by the way, if(cell == nil) is not necessary. 

This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class or nib file you previously registered. If no cell is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil.

Comment: Need more details in `customCell`. How do you set text in your cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

In custom cell, you must to resign "identifier" for reuse this cell in .xib file

[image: resign "Indentifier" in nib]

Comment: what i have to mention in Identifier?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below in your cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
if ([cell.contentView subviews]){
        for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you.